# Can't set correct display resolution

Tags: debian, xorg, intel-graphics, resolution, graphic-card

I have current Debian testing, can't set resolution for display dell U2718Q:

```
# inxi -Gxx
Graphics:  Card: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
           bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0116
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.5 ) drivers: intel
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGl: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile
           version: 3.3 Mesa 17.2.5 (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: yes
```

/etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Indentifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver       "intel"
    Option       "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option       "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

But it didn't help with resolution.

I try to set:

```
# xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 3840x2160_60.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

I tried also with option --crtc, but there is no result.

xrandr output:

```
# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192 
LVDS-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      60.10 +
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 609mm x 349mm
   2048x1280     59.99  
   2048x1080     24.00  
   1920x1080     60.00*   60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94    50.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   3840x2160_60.00  59.98  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have xserver-xorg-video-intel, xserver-xorg-video-all, xserver-xorg-core packages installed.

Please any help.

Upd:

Processor: Intel Core i5-2467M CPU @ 1.60GHz x 2

port: HDMI 2.0

/var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
[    18.449] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    18.456] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    18.469] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.469]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 2.99.917
[    18.469]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.469]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    18.469] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
        i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
        915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
        Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
        GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    18.470] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    18.470] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[    18.470] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[    18.490] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20170403
[    18.490] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20161206-1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[    18.490] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    18.494] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000
```

Comment: Which port are you using to connect your monitor?

Comment: What is the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: @StephenKitt HDMI

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams posted in question.

Comment: What CPU do you have?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Intel Core i5-2467M CPU @ 1.60GHz x 2, posted

Comment: You want to look at /var/log/Xorg.0.log to see what Xorg actually did when it started. Look down the file and you'll see the various modules load and unload, that's roughly what inxi is reporting there by the way. In your case, it's clear that the intel driver never loaded or unloaded or it would show in that inxi driver list as either loaded or unloaded or failed. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics that talks more about the intel/modesetting issue, but it's too much info I think.

Comment: @Lizardx Move back xorg conf make load intel module fine. Has no errrors about it. Post updated with xorg log.

Comment: On Intel GPUs the recommended X.org driver is `modesetting`, not `intel` (any more). However it’s worth trying the `xrandr` modeline definitions using the `intel` driver too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandy Bridge’s outputs don’t have enough bandwidth to support your monitor’s full resolution at 60Hz, however it should be possible to create a mode which will get you some of the way there.

[This article](https://medium.com/@ValdikSS/how-to-use-high-resolutions-with-older-hardware-58577d91b1f8) gives details on the calculation process. In your case, the important factors are that your monitor’s native resolution is 3840×2160, and that HDMI 1.4 has a maximum pixel clock of 340MHz. Using [`umc`](http://umc.sourceforge.net/), we can use this to determine an appropriate mode line:

```
$ umc 3840 2160 340000000

    # 3840x2160x30.00 @ 65.994kHz
    Modeline "3840x2160x30.00"  340.000000  3840 4080 4496 5152  2160 2164 2168 2200  -HSync +VSync
```

To try this, run

```
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160x30.00"  340.000000  3840 4080 4496 5152  2160 2164 2168 2200  -HSync +VSync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "3840x2160x30.00"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "3840x2160x30.00"
```

If it proves too high for the integrated GPU, or the monitor doesn’t like it, you can try reducing the pixel clock, or reducing the blanking timing (which should be fine on a modern screen):

```
$ umc 3840 2160 30 --rbt

    # 3840x2160x29.98 @ 65.688kHz
    Modeline "3840x2160x29.98"  262.750000  3840 3888 3920 4000  2160 2163 2167 2191  +HSync -VSync
```

Once you have a working mode line, you can store it permanently by adding a configuration file, say `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-hdmi-4k.conf`, containing:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-1"
    ModelName "Your monitor"
    Modeline "3840x2160x29.98"  262.750000  3840 3888 3920 4000  2160 2163 2167 2191  +HSync -VSync
EndSection
```

Comment: Thank you for link, how can I calculate correct parameters? I have HDMI 2.0 and try: 3200x1600_30.00 - failed configure, 3200x1600_29.00 - display show error message, 2560x1440_60.00 - failed, 2560x1440_34.00 - display show error message. (display dell U2718Q)

Comment: Sandy Bridge only supports HDMI 1.4, regardless of the kind of cable you have (which doesn’t make any difference) or the level of support in your monitor. You probably need to look up supported frequencies in your monitor’s manual, the modes that display error messages on the monitor might well have frequencies that are too low.